# HTTP Request using NuSoap

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I am trying to re-create the following XML request using NuSoap and send to a server. The server expects a request that looks like the following.

```
POST /UserRegistratoin/services/Register/ HTTP/1.0
Host: 192.168.0.3:9000
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 899

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v2="http://www.ipma.com.cn/schema/common/v2_1"
xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/payment/amount_charging/v2_1/local">
<soapenv:Header>
<v2:RequestSOAPHeader>
        <v2:User>895545</v2:User>
        <v2:Password>098833</v2:Password>
        <v2:timeStamp>20230303060629</v2:timeStamp>
        </v2:RequestSOAPHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<chargeAmount>
<endUserIdentifier>737329292929</endUserIdentifier>
<referenceCode>2</referenceCode>
</chargeAmount>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to provide the NS for the `RequestSOAPHeader`

Comment: Will you be more specific,  Chris Haas? FYI the request works well via PostMan. i.e returns a 200 response xml.

Comment: Can someone please advise how to include headers in a request? $client->setHeaders($headers); is not working.

Comment: Try one of [these two](https://3v4l.org/vlAug). (The code on that site won’t run since nu_soap isn’t installed there, it I just convenient to post samples to.)

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://f00b4r.github.io/nusoap/nusoap/nusoap_base.html#methodserializeEnvelope), looks like the headers are the second parameter to `serializeEnvelope`, so try passing them there. Or pass `false` to let the other call go through.

Comment: Maybe you have a good reason to use it, but in case you just found it in an old tutorial, note that NuSOAP has had very little maintenance for over 10 years, and PHP has [built-in SOAP classes](https://php.net/soap) which would probably be better for new code.